# Sending and Receiving SMS from J2EE application using GSM phone. How to?

Tags: jakarta-ee, sms

I am developing a application using J2EE and the specifications of project requires SMS based query to some information.

1. Any user sends a text message in predefined format.
2. User get a autoresponder about current information.

   I heard about SMSlib but dont know if this library can give me what i want.

Advice please.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

A library does not send SMS.
Your first decision is for how to physically send and receive the SMS - you have the choice between building your own Gateway, via GSM modem and SIM card, or using a commercial service provider (e.g. http://message-media.com/ is the first one that Google spit out). SMSlib or other APIs help you with the former. If you use a service, you have to go with the vendor's API.

Answer (score 0):

[Zeep Mobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/) offers a free SMS with a Short Code but you might want to look into and [Aggregator](http://www.openmarket.com/) if your planning to high volumes of SMS messaging or Charge a fee for your service.